# How can I get a specific response value from response body in postman

Tags: json, postman, response

```
{
    "Group": "4r3rwee",
    "EventType": "string",
    "EventId": "string",
    "Payload": "{\"Id\":\"6fd04f93e22e44c98752e209c1b74b03\",\"Name\":\"Md. Sakibur Rahman\",\"Email\":\"sakibur.rahmandd773661@orbitax.com \",\"Phone\":\"string\",\"Title\":\"Add Contact\",\"Status\":1,\"ContactType\":0,\"CompanyId\":\"automation\",\"ProjectId\":\"\"}",
    "Status": 1,
    "Id": "57c9c52a645a40f5bed0562dbee7d13b"
}
```

How can I get Id value from the payload?

I am using this command, but it's not working

```
pm.test("Set Contacts ID", function () {
    var jsonData = pm.response.json();

    //console.log("Response Payload : " + jsonData.Payload.{jsonData.Id});
    pm.environment.set("contactIds", jsonData.Payload.Id);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the request data shown in the question, param. `Payload` contains JSON string. So, you'd need to parse it first, to access the property as follows,

```
pm.test("Set Contacts ID", function () {
    var jsonData = pm.response.json();
    var payloadData = JSON.parse(jsonData.Payload); //parsed payload

    console.log(payloadData.Id);

    pm.environment.set("contactIds", payloadData.Id);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but its Not Working

Comment: Payload is in response body not in header

Comment: Instead of setting Id value in 'contactIds' environment variable, its sets the whole payload value in Environment variable.

Comment: I used your code. but it's not returning my expected value. I want to get the ID value from Payload                                                                                                   
{
  "Payload": "{\"Id\":\"6fd04f93e22e44c98752e209c1b74b03\",\"Name\":\"Md. 
            Sakibur Rahman\",\"Email\":\"sakibur.rahmandd773661@orbitax.com 
            \",\"Phone\":\"string\",\"Title\":\"Add Contact\",\"Status\":1,\"ContactType\":0,\"CompanyId\":\"automation\",\"ProjectId\":\"\"}"
}

Comment: I used an environment variable named contactIds and I want to set its value from response header. the value will get from Payload >Id

Comment: @DivI am getting the error 
AIL Set Contacts ID | JSONError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0

Comment: Thanks for the solution. Its working fine. The error was var payloadData = JSON.parse(jsonData.payload) . It should be var payloadData = JSON.parse(jsonData.Payload); "P" should be capital in the Payload